# Get pairs of positive values efficiently with numpy

Tags: python, logging, numpy, filter

I have a python function which takes in two lists, looks for pairs in the two inputs where both have positive values at the same index, and creates two output lists by appending to each one of those two positive values. I have a working function:

```
def get_pairs_in_first_quadrant(x_in, y_in):
    """If both x_in[i] and y_in[i] are > 0 then both will appended to the output list. If either are negative
    then the pair of them will be absent from the output list.
    :param x_in: A list of positive or negative floats
    :param y_in: A list of positive or negative floats
    :return: A list of positive floats <= in length to the inputs.
    """
    x_filtered, y_filtered = [], []
    for x, y in zip(x_in, y_in):
        if x > 0 and y > 0:
            x_filtered.append(x)
            y_filtered.append(y)
    return x_filtered, y_filtered
```

How can I make this faster using numpy?

Comment: Use [numpy.logical_and](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html).

Comment: How big are the lists we're talking about here?

Comment: Length could be around 100 000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by simply finding the indices where they are both positive:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(10) - .5
b = np.random.random(10) - .5

def get_pairs_in_first_quadrant(x_in, y_in):
    i = np.nonzero( (x_in>0) & (y_in>0) )   # main line of interest
    return x_in[i], y_in[i]

print a  # [-0.18012451 -0.40924713 -0.3788772   0.3186816   0.14811581 -0.04021951 -0.21278312 -0.36762629 -0.45369899 -0.46374929]
print b  # [ 0.33005969 -0.03167875  0.11387641  0.22101336  0.38412264 -0.3880842 0.08679424  0.3126209  -0.08760505 -0.40921421]
print get_pairs_in_first_quadrant(a, b)   # (array([ 0.3186816 ,  0.14811581]), array([ 0.22101336,  0.38412264]))
```

---

I was interested in Jaime's suggestion to just using the boolean indexing without calling `nonzero` so I ran some timing tests.  The results are somewhat interesting since they advantage ratio is non-monotonic with the number of positive matches, but basically, at least for speed, it doesn't really matter which is used (though `nonzero` is usually a bit faster, and can be about twice as fast):

```
threshold = .6
a = np.random.random(10000) - threshold
b = np.random.random(10000) - threshold

def f1(x_in, y_in):
    i = np.nonzero( (x_in>0) & (y_in>0) )   # main line of interest
    return x_in[i], y_in[i]

def f2(x_in, y_in):
    i = (x_in>0) & (y_in>0)  # main line of interest
    return x_in[i], y_in[i]

print threshold, len(f1(a,b)[0]), len(f2(a,b)[0])
print timeit("f1(a, b)", "from __main__ import a, b, f1, f2", number = 1000)
print timeit("f2(a, b)", "from __main__ import a, b, f1, f2", number = 1000)
```

Which gives, for different threshold values:

```
0.05 9086 9086
0.0815141201019
0.104746818542

0.5 2535 2535
0.0715141296387
0.153401851654

0.95 21 21
0.027126789093
0.0324990749359
```

Comment: Don't call `np.nonzero` on the boolean array: use it directly to index `x_in` and `y_in`.

Comment: @Jaime: I ran a speed test, and it seems to not make much difference.  Is there another reason to prefer the boolean array?

Comment: Are you using numpy 1.9? There was a big improvement in indexing in that release, it seems my intuitions are outdated... If you were to index a single array, boolean would still marginally come ahead, but obviously not for more arrays.